# Signing PDF with HTTPS and Tcpdf?

Tags: php, pdf, https, digital-signature, tcpdf

Is it possible to retrieve/parse the information of [$_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_CERT']](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#envvars) and sign a PDF using [setSignature()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a1184d1ac9ef4d6313bf23ddba45936dc) of Tcpdf?

In our web-app, it will be necessary to create pdfs on-the-fly and sign them using the client certificate.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SSL_CLIENT_CERT` has only public key so you won't be able to sign anything this way.

To sign something with a X.509 certificate you must have access to its private key. This means that only the owner of the certificate can sign anything using the software that will have access to the private key. So it's impossible to sign by a server with user's certificate. Using public key you will be able only to encrypt data.

Unfortunately, since Java applets are basically unusable today, you will have hard time getting this to work in browsers. Maybe [PKI.js](https://github.com/GlobalSign/PKI.js) will help, but I don't know if it will work with hardware tokens (PKCS#11).

Recently I was tasked to came up with solution to similar problem, and I made a desktop application (only for Windows, using .NET [SecureBlackbox library](https://www.eldos.com/sbb/)) sitting in the tray, that polls periodically the server for documents to sign, fetches them, signs and returns signed to the server.

Comment: Okay...Is it a Apache/PHP limitation or is it impossible on a web server context? Even with dongle/token?